# USB tethering issue in android studio

Tags: android, usb, tethering

I'm new to android. When I turn on USB tethering in my phone, my device is not recognized by the PC while on turning off the tethering device gets recognized.Please suggest me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your phone settings > about Phone > Build number tap 5 to 7 time and you got developers menu in settings enter that menu and turn on USB Debugging hope fix it

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Phone Setting
Next Click about Phone
Build number tap 5 to 7 time
and you get developers menu in settings
Enter that menu and turn on USB Debugging .
Select USB COnfiguration ==>>set MTP(Media Trafer Protol)